# php laravel eloquent: is it possible to build an update query with SET WHEN

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent, fluent

```
UPDATE tbl
   SET colB = CASE colA 
      WHEN a THEN x 
      WHEN b THEN y 
   END
 WHERE colB IN(a, b);
```

Is there a way to build above query with eloquent / fluent?

Comment: You can write two simple update statements. One for `a` and one for `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Split it in two update queries to keep your code simple:

```php
DB::table('tbl')
    ->where('colA', 'a')
    ->whereIn('colB', ['a', 'b'])
    ->update(['colB' => 'x']);

DB::table('tbl')
    ->where('colA', 'b')
    ->whereIn('colB', ['a', 'b'])
    ->update(['colB' => 'y']);
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not an option since the actual update contains many more value pairs to update

Comment: Then use a raw query (`DB::statement("...")`). IMHO it doesn't make sence to use the query builder if most of the code contains raw expressions (`DB::raw("...")`).